# Tuple deconstruction in pattern matching

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I'm looking at what's new in c# after a long break and trying to understand how generic type matching works. At the same time I'm wondering if it is possible to deconstruct a tuple in the pattern, e.g.:

```cs
string SendIt<T>(T p) => p switch
{
    ValueTuple<int, int> t => $"int point {t.Item1}, {t.Item2}", // <- this works
    (float x, float y)     => $"float point {x}, {y}",           // <- this doesn't
    _                      => $"dunno, type={typeof(T)}",
};
```

Comment: How are you calling `SendIt`? Does this code compile ?

Comment: It doesn't work for generic `<T>`, but it does work for `object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `does not work` case you are trying to deconstruct something totally unknown (`T` without any constraints) into two elements. In this case compiler will try to search `static void Deconstruct<T>(this T val, out float x, out float y)` somewhere in will fail (anyway I can't imagine how can such a function looks like for absolutely unspecified `T`). So, it won't compile.

First line (which compiles) using the cast, so it will just handle all in runtime (and just will not go into the branch if cast will be impossible)

As for the question about tuple deconstruction, then here we go - just fix declaration of the tuple, explicitly saying that it is a tuple and there is two elements inside.

```
string SendIt<T1, T2>(Tuple<T1, T2> p) => p switch
{
    (float x, float y) => $"float point {x}, {y}", 
    _ => $"dunno, type={typeof(T)}",
};

Console.WriteLine(SendIt(Tuple.Create(2f,3f))); //float point 2, 3
Console.WriteLine(SendIt(Tuple.Create(2,"test"))); //dunno, type=System.Int32
```

We can also go further with cast approach, so

```
string SendIt<T>(T p) => p switch
{
    ValueTuple<int, int> t => $"int point {t.Item1}, {t.Item2}", 
    Tuple<float, float>(float x, float y) => $"float point {x}, {y}", 
    _ => $"dunno, type={typeof(T)}",
};

Console.WriteLine(SendIt(ValueTuple.Create(1,2))); // int point 1, 2
Console.WriteLine(SendIt(Tuple.Create(1f,2f))); //float point 1, 2

Console.WriteLine(SendIt(Tuple.Create(1,2))); dunno, type=System.Tuple`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]
```

Comment: or change the type of the parameter to `object`.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like the `object` is some special case. At least `SendIt<T>() when T: class` does not give such an effect.